# JavaScript regex for calculations

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to match individual characters from a calculation string such as:

```
(123+321)*1.15
```

The list of characters I'd like to match is:

```
0-9, ., +, -, *, /, (, ), %
```

Each character of the string will be passed into a function individually. I think I have the starting point (which works great with the numbers):

```
if (character.match(/[0-9]{1}/) !== null) {
    // do something...
}
```

I'm not quite sure how to add the remaining characters though (I've always found regex confusing, even after reading countless articles on the subject).

Comment: You'll have more luck parsing it character-by-character.

Comment: You just want to check if a character is one of those?

Comment: @Dogbert Yes. That's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add the characters you want with the `0-9`, like

```
character.match(/[0-9.+\-*/()%]/)
```

The only character needing to be escaped in the RegExp is `-`, as it normally means a range of characters.

There's no need of `{1}` as the default is to match 1 instance.